# Simple method for finding and replacing string linux

Tags: sed, grep

I'm currently trying to find a line in a file

```
#define IMAX 8000
```

and replacing 8000 with another number.

Currently, stuck trying to pipe arguments from awk into sed.

```
grep '#define IMAX' 1d_Euler_mpi_test.c | awk '{print $3}' | sed
```

Not too sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Oops my bad! Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use GNU sed.

```
sed -i -e 's/IMAX 8000/IMAX 9000/g' /tmp/file.txt
```

Which will invoke sed to do an in-place edit due to the -i option. This can be called from bash.

If you really really want to use just bash, then the following can work:

```
while read a ; do echo ${a//IMAX 8000/IMAX 9000} ; done < /tmp/file.txt > /tmp/file.txt.t ; mv /tmp/file.txt{.t,}
```

This loops over each line, doing a substitution, and writing to a temporary file (don't want to clobber the input). The move at the end just moves temporary to the original name.

Comment: I think this will mess up the constant. Shouldn't it be `IMAX 9000`?

Comment: Note that your usage of `-i` implies GNU sed. The question didn't specify a variant. For that reason and to retain value to a wider audience, you might want to provide more portable usage, or at least clarify that what tooling is required to make use of your answer.

Comment: Updated the response to specify GNU sed.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Place new number's value in place of `new_number` too.(tested this with GNU `sed`)

```
echo "#define IMAX 8000" | sed -E '/#define IMAX /s/[0-9]+$/new_number/'
```

In case you are reading input from an Input_file and want to save its output into Input_file itself use following then.

```
sed -E '/#define IMAX /s/[0-9]+$/new_number/' Input_file
```

Add `-i` flag in above code in case you want to save output into Input_file itself. Also my codes will catch any digits which are coming at the end of the line which has string `#define IMAX` so in case you only want to look for `8000` or any fixed number change `[0-9]+$` to `8000` etc in above codes then.

Comment: I always forget about the capital *E* flag and it's always nice to see

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
sed -i '' '/^#define IMAX 8000$/s/8000/NEW_NUMBER/' 1d_Euler_mpi_test.c
```